# Have navbar slide down at a specific point on a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey everyone I've been learning js and HTML and I've been trying hard to learn alot.

I have a navbar that I want to trigger at a certain part of my page (via scrolling). Right now the code I have forces the navbar to keep fading in and out in an endless loop.

Here's my Javascript:

```
  $('.navbarclass').hide(0);

  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
        var scroll_pos_test = 150;        

        if(y_scroll_pos > scroll_pos_test) {
          $('.navbarclass').slideToggle();
        }

    });
```

Basically I want the navbar to trigger at 150 (which it does) but it keeps looping the toggle in and out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is looping in the toggle because the condition will be always true after you have scrolled the 150px. Hence, each scroll greater than 150px will make the navbar slideDown or slideUp.

I would do the conditional in this way.

```
if (y_scroll_pos > scroll_pos_test) {
    $('.navbarclass').slideDown();
} else {
    $('.navbarclass').slideUp();
}
```

This will slideDown the navbar when the scroll is greater than 150px and will slideUp when is less or equal than 150px.

If you just want it to be shown when the scroll is greater than 150px and do nothing else, just delete the else block.

Answer (score 0):

Change `.slideToggle()` to `.slideDown()`

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.